# If Dispose(bool) is overridden, will resources still be disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In this MSDN example, if Dispose(bool) is overridden in a subclass, will the Dispose(bool) code in this base class ever be executed?  I.E. will resource.Dispose() ever get called?  Do subclasses need to call base.Dispose(true)?

```
public class DisposableResourceHolder : IDisposable {

    private SafeHandle resource; // handle to a resource

    public DisposableResourceHolder(){
        this.resource = ... // allocates the resource
    }

    public void Dispose(){
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){
        if (disposing){
            if (resource!= null) resource.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course. When you override a method you need to call the base class for it to be executed.

Comment: It is a pretty standard example of getting it *completely* wrong.  There is no point in implementing the pattern, the class does not have a finalizer and does not inherit a base class that forced Disposable(bool) to be overridden.  You can always tell by having nothing useful to do when *disposing* is false.

Comment: As @Hans says, the pattern is inappropriate here.  Some people recommend implementing the pattern just in case a derived class owns unmanaged resources -- that's complete rubbish.  The derived class can reimplement `IDisposable`, add the finalizer, and provide `virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) { if (disposing) { base.Dispose(); } }`  A base subobject is similar in many many respects to a member subobject, including that its `Dispose()` method should be called when the complete object gets disposed.

Comment: (But don't implement `IDisposable.Dispose()` explicitly in any non-final class, since this will prevent any derived class from calling `base.Dispose()`)

Comment: @BenVoigt: An advantage of using a sealed outside-callable `Dispose` method1 which chains to a virtual one is that it allows for the insertion of base-class logic at a time when the object is still valid.  For example, if the base class attaches asynchronous event handlers, it could use the `sealed` dispose method to safely disable them and wait for pending calls to complete before having derived-class objects start dismantling themselves.

Comment: @supercat: You can't seal interface implementations except by sealing your entire class.  Your arrangement can also be implemented by documenting that derived classes should call `base.Dispose()` before disposing other objects.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Explicit interface definitions are inherently sealed; one can't (alas) prevent re-implementation, but one can force any code which in any way uses the existing implementation to do so through the supplied method.  As for having derived methods call a base "prepare for disposing" method, that can work, but having the base chain to the derived method allows the base to wrap the chaining statement in a `try/finally` block.  It would also make it possible to have a `Dispose` which occurs as an asynchronous request is received to set a flag and return immediately...

Comment: ...and then have the asynchronous event handler chain to `Dispose` once all pending events have finished.  To be sure, in most cases `Dispose` shouldn't be called on an object which might be in use, but for objects which receive asynchronous events, the best one can do is ask the object to stop receiving events and clean up once any events received before the "stop" have finished.

Comment: @supercat: I definitely think that asynchronous shutdown (by masking future events and then queuing the cleanup request to the same queue used for asynchronous events) is a good mechanism for objects with asynchronous events.  But that wouldn't be a good implementation of `IDisposable`, it should be a separate public method.

Comment: @BenVoigt: While client code should generally call a "stop taking requests" method prior to calling `Dispose`, I would suggest that whenever possible all objects should either be safe to abandon or else implement a `Dispose` method which will ensure that any necessary cleanup will get done.  The `Dispose` method may be rather blunt in its behavior, and other methods might be "nicer", but `Dispose` should at least be sufficient to allow the class to abide by any contracts it has with other objects that are acting on its behalf.

Comment: @supercat: If the object is disposed without properly waiting for asynchronous shutdown to occur, then one should expect `ObjectDisposedException` spammed in the event handlers.  The nice thing about garbage collection is that the object remains in existence as long as there's any way to reach it, so events that weren't aborted in time won't suffer wild pointers, only access to already-disposed objects.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Depending upon what the events are doing, it may be very desirable to ensure that requests are either declined cleanly or, once accepted, run to completion.  Bear in mind that the "client" might be on another computer someplace connected via socket link.  I would see no reason `Dispose` should not attempt to be as graceful as practical in its behavior.  BTW, your "wild pointers" comment is why I think a good framework should combine the principles of RAII and GC.  RAII is good at managing resources, but GC is good at catching potential RAII mistakes.

Comment: @supercat: In order to do that, the controller needs to handle the event indicating completion of asynchronous shutdown.  I don't feel like that's appropriate behavior for Dispose.  I guess Dispose could be a blocking (synchronous) shutdown.  That still has no relation to inheritance, though.  The most-derived object handles the Dispose call, and is responsible for disposing all subobjects, whether used by inheritance or composition.

Comment: @BenVoigt: If the call to `Dispose(bool)` is made by logic in the base class, rather than unconditionally chained from `IDisposable.Dispose`, then the base class can take care of calling `Dispose(bool)` when it's safe to do so.  The code which called `IDisposable.Dispose` would not be told whether or when it completed, since the act of calling `Dispose` strongly implied that *it no longer cared about the object, and was only telling the object that because it thought the object should know*.

Comment: @supercat: In your design, it's always safe to call `base.Dispose()`, because that is what sets of the chain of events of unsubscribing asynchronous events and processing already-queued events.

Comment: @supercat: And the code which called `IDisposable.Dispose` should definitely know when it is completed.  It's expressing a promise not to use the object any further, which is very different from leaving the object to its own devices.  I might want to disconnect a VPN right after calling Dispose on a network stream with unsaved data -- it is NOT OK for the object to return from Dispose and still own or require the use of any resources.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I would suggest that code which wants to know the state of the connection should do something other than `Dispose` it.  Having `Dispose` block is fine when the duration of the block will be short, but what if it could be minutes or more?  Having `Dispose` return before cleanup is complete may make it necessary for code which opens a new connection to ensure that there isn't a lingering connection from before, but I'd see that as sometimes being a lesser-of-evils approach.

Comment: @supercat: At this point you're not talking about `IDisposable` anymore.  Because there's a lot of precedent in the BCL for disposing a stream to guarantee it is flushed.  Disposing a BinaryWriter guarantees it is flushed (and you may now close the stream as well).  And disposing a FileStream unlocks the file so you may reopen it (barring broken antivirus that takes exclusive locks on files)

Comment: And none of this justifies inverting the control, anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's standard for classes which override `Dispose()` to call `base.Dispose()`.  If a class has overridden `Dispose` then its base class will only execute its implementation if it's explicitly called.  If your override doesn't defer to the base class then you have effectively assumed its responsibilities--which is not typically desirable.

It's also worth adding error handling within your implementation in the form of a `try/finally` block.  Use the `finally` block to call the base `Dispose` method; this prevents exceptions in your implementation from preventing its base classes from disposing.

---

[CA2215: Dispose methods should call base class dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182330.aspx) (below text is duplicated from this source)

**Cause**

A type that implements System.IDisposable inherits from a type that also implements IDisposable. The Dispose method of the inheriting type does not call the Dispose method of the parent type.

**Rule Description**

If a type inherits from a disposable type, it must call the Dispose method of the base type from within its own Dispose method. Calling the base type method Dispose ensures that any resources created by the base type are released.

**How to Fix Violations**

To fix a violation of this rule, call base.Dispose in your Dispose method.

**When to Suppress Warnings**

It is safe to suppress a warning from this rule if the call to base.Dispose occurs at a deeper calling level than the rule checks.